# Why is the PPA version of LibreOffice-fresh older than the one on the site?

Tags: libreoffice

ppa version of libre office fresh is 5.0.3-2 and the deb file is 5.0.4. Aren't ppa's always up to date? What is their purpose then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PPA likely will require the packages being specially uploaded and built for PPA distribution which will take time. According to the [release notes](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/release-notes/#Fresh), it *(RC2 version at a guess*) was released only yesterday (17th Dec 2015), so you will have to wait a little while yet

You can get 5.0.4 via the downloading the packages from the website [here](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/)  - note you may need to update these manually and the packages will likely install as `libreoffice5.0-*`, so may try and install alongside the existing version in `/opt` instead of updating the `libreoffice-*` packages.

See also:

- [Release Schedule](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/ReleasePlan/5.0)